# Installing wget: how do you verify that the wget source code has not been altered?

Tags: wget

I am unable to find an md5 or sha-1 code to verify the wget download at http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/.  There is a .sig file next to the download at http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/:

```
...
wget-1.16.tar.gz
wget-1.16.tar.gz.sig
...
```

So I downloaded both of those, but I cannot open the .sig file.

In order to use the .sig file to verify the wget source download, I installed GPGSuite (for Mac OSX 10.10.2), and then I did:

```
$ gpg ~/Downloads/wget-1.16.tar.gz.sig 
gpg: assuming signed data in '/Users/7stud/Downloads/wget-1.16.tar.gz'
gpg: Signature made Mon Oct 27 03:04:05 2014 MDT using RSA key ID E163E1EA
gpg: requesting key E163E1EA from hkps server hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: key E163E1EA: public key "Giuseppe Scrivano <giuseppe@scrivano.org>" imported
gpg: 3 marginal(s) needed, 1 complete(s) needed, PGP trust model
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   2  signed:   0  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 2u
gpg: next trustdb check due at 2018-08-19
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
gpg: Good signature from "Giuseppe Scrivano <giuseppe@scrivano.org>" [unknown]
gpg:                 aka "Giuseppe Scrivano <gscrivano@gnu.org>" [unknown]
gpg:                 aka "Giuseppe Scrivano <gscrivan@redhat.com>" [unknown]
gpg:                 aka "Giuseppe Scrivano <gscrivano@gmail.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: AC40 4C1C 0BF7 35C6 3FF4  D562 263D 6DF2 E163 E1EA
```

But the WARNING makes me feel like I have not verified anything.

Isn't there an md5 or sha-1 code somewhere?

**Response to comment:**

```
~/Downloads$ gpg --verify wget-1.16.tar.gz.sig wget-1.16.tar.gz
gpg: Signature made Mon Oct 27 03:04:05 2014 MDT using RSA key ID E163E1EA
gpg: Good signature from "Giuseppe Scrivano <giuseppe@scrivano.org>" [unknown]
gpg:                 aka "Giuseppe Scrivano <gscrivano@gnu.org>" [unknown]
gpg:                 aka "Giuseppe Scrivano <gscrivan@redhat.com>" [unknown]
gpg:                 aka "Giuseppe Scrivano <gscrivano@gmail.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: AC40 4C1C 0BF7 35C6 3FF4  D562 263D 6DF2 E163 E1EA
```

Comment: Have you tried `gpg --verify <your_sig.sig> <your_file>`? (https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x135.html) As for the public key of the person who has signed the `tar` it should be somewhere on a PGP key server.

Comment: @rbaleksandar, I get a truncated version of the same output--see my edit. I don't know what I am supposed to do with that output to verify that the wget source has not been altered.

Comment: And....the output from the first command seems to include a lookup of the key from a PGP key sever.

Comment: True. Btw [this](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/6843/38026) might provide some clarification on the warning.

Comment: From the output, I seem to know the following: 1) The key E163E1EA is owned by Giuseppe Scrivano; 2) The wget source file was signed with the key E163E1EA.  However, apparently anyone can sign a file with the key E163E1EA, so there is no guarantee that Giuseppe Scrivano produced the wget source file.  In other words, a hacker could have posted the wget source file and signed it with the key E163E1EA, and if I install it, my system could be compromised.  But then, a hacker could post the wget source file and an sha-1 code for the hacked wget source, and I would be in the same position.  Hmm...

Comment: I flagged your question and asked for it to be moved to http://security.stackexchange.com/. I think you will be better served there then here. This question is all about security and it has little to do with programming.

Comment: @rbaleksandar, Okay, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have published my GPG key here: http://pgp.mit.edu/pks/lookup?op=vindex&search=0x263D6DF2E163E1EA

Sadly it has not many signatures yet, as I have changed my old one (1024 bits) that I used for years for signing releases: http://pgp.mit.edu/pks/lookup?op=vindex&search=0x0791AF8CC03363F4

Comment: Hey, Giuseppe Schrivano!   I'm new to gpg, so I don't really know what I'm doing.  Is what I said in my comment true? Can anyone sign a file with your public key?  And, what additional steps do I need to take to verify a download, like wget.   In other words, when I read the WARNING in the gpg output(in my question), how do I go about making sure the file hasn't been tampered with?

Comment: no, not everyone can sign a file with my public key.

Have you downloaded my public key with "gpg --recv-key E163E1EA" first?